# OpenCV com Python ocorre um erro "Assertion failed"

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Recentemente comecei a trabalhar com OpenCV no Python. Pois bem, estou fazendo um código aqui e, ao compilar, dá o seguinte erro:

```
Ocorreu uma exceção: error
OpenCV(4.4.0) /tmp/pip-req-build-a3np7pha/opencv/modules/core/src/batch_distance.cpp:282: error: (-215:Assertion failed) (type == CV_8U && dtype == CV_32S) || dtype == CV_32F in function 'batchDistance'
  File "/home/vivi/Documentos/GitHub/LAPISCO/PYTHON_OPCV/QUESTÃO51/questão51.py", line 30, in <module>
    matches = bf.match(descriptors_1, descriptors_2)
```

Alguém, com mais experiência, poderia me dizer o que exatamente está acontecendo? Confesso que estou meio perdida.

Segue o código:

```
# Utilizar o método Scale Invariant Feature Transform (SIFT) para detectar onde 
# está um objeto conhecido à priori em uma imagem através dos keypoints
# detectados #por este método. Desenhar os keypoints em comum e marcar o objeto procurado na imagem.

import cv2

# Read the rgb images
image = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
logo = cv2.imread('logo.jpg')

# Convert the images to grayscale
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
logo = cv2.cvtColor(logo, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Create a SIFT detector (Obs.: in order to use sift descriptor you will have to install opencv-contrib
# from scratch. An alternative to that is to use opencv implementation called orb, it has almost the
# same result. To use orb, comment the lines with sift and uncomment the lines with orb.)
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
# orb = cv2.ORB_create()

# Find the keypoints and descriptors with SIFT
keypoints_1, descriptors_1 = sift.detectAndCompute(image, None)
keypoints_2, descriptors_2 = sift.detectAndCompute(logo, None)

# keypoints_1, descriptors_1 = orb.detectAndCompute(image, None)
# keypoints_2, descriptors_2 = orb.detectAndCompute(logo, None)

# Create a BFMatcher object
bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)

# Match descriptors
matches = bf.match(descriptors_1, descriptors_2)

# Draw only the first match
result = cv2.drawMatches(image, keypoints_1, logo, keypoints_2, matches[:2], None, flags=2)

# Show the result
cv2.imshow('Result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# Save the result
cv2.imwrite('sift_result.jpg', result)
```

Comment: O SIFT não foi removido do OpenCV na versão 3.5?

Comment: Veja se este [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39940766/bfmatcher-match-in-opencv-throwing-error) ajuda.

Comment: Parece que o SIFT não é instalado por default, mas pode ser instaldo.

Comment: Hmm, entendi... COmo o SIFT tava dando erro, eu usei o orb e deu mais ou menos certo... Por que as correspondências começaram a ficar trocadas.